# How to setup redis develop env

Tags: redis, development-environment

I'm asking about how to setup an environment for the development of redis, not a environment with redis setup.

I'm currently using vs-code installed in ubuntu, but I think that I'm gonna need gdb or something else to leverage.

It would be much appreciated if anyone could kindly answer my question.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Trying to do some code work on redis, to enable multi-direction-replication